# Three,js get mesh outside the loader

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, module, three.js, gltf

I am working on a project using Three.js.
And, I am trying get mesh(gltf.scene) in the GLTF load from outside, but it says it is undefined if I console.log outside of the loader. I spent hours to figure this out but haven't able to solve this problem. I am guessing this is happening because it is asynchronous, but I am not so sure.
This is my first attempt to use javascript class format, so I am little bit confused. Usually it worked if I declare variable on the higher scope and assign the mesh to it but does not work this time.

```
class mainCharacter {
  constructor(game) {
...
...
...
this.character;
this.loader = new GLTFLoader();
this.loader.load("./c.glb",(gltf)=>{
this.character= gltf.scene;
});
console.log(this.character);


}
```

I also tried to do async function but did not work.

```
class mainCharacter {
  constructor(game) {
...
...
...
this.character;
this.loadMain();
console.log(this.character);
})

async loadMain(){
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    this.character = await loader.loadAsync("./c.glb");
    this.character.scene.scale.set(13, 13, 13);
    this.scene.add(this.character.scene);
}
```

Seems like it works if I use await in front of the loadMain() and console.log(this.character), but I cannot use await in the constructor function, since it is not async function.
If anyone have any idea, please help me out :'(

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to ThreeJS documentation (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/Loader.loadAsync), the method loadAsync does not return the loaded mesh, instead, it return a Promise event.

```
.loadAsync ( url : String, onProgress : Function ) : Promise
```

Therefore, you would need to declare a onLoad callback function like below:

```
this.character = await loader.loadAsync("./c.glb").then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "Success"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define another static method (like `load` shown below) in your class and pass `this` as a parameter

```
class mainCharacter {
  constructor(game) {
    ...
    this.character;
    this.loader;
    mainCharacter.load(this);
    ...
  }
  static load(self) {
    self.loader = new GLTFLoader();
    self.loader.load(
      "./c.glb",
      (gltf) => self.character = gltf.scene
    );
  }
}
```

in arrow functions, `this` points to the owner of that function, or the object in which that particular arrow function is defined.
in your case, `this` inside the arrow function does not point to the `mainCharacter` object because its actually defined in and passed on to the `loader.load()` function.
See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp for more details.